# URL Concatenation is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, content-area

I used the Url Concatenation in the Cloud page and i stored the content into Content Area using Ssjs script and then pulled into the email and when  I preview that email Url concatenation working but after sent that email Url concatenation not working during sending time

Comment: Can you please post a copy of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your URL are using a special character which isn't supported in the moment of delivery. try change it